# Can you breed wolves, and if you can how? In D&D

Tags: house-rules

So in my first time Playing I tamed two wolves can I breed them? And if I can how do you do it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. Can you tell us which edition of D&D you're asking about?

Comment: How would you do that

Comment: @MicahBrotnov Same way you added the house-rules tag.

Comment: @MicahBrotnov I've got an answer for you, but I'm only guessing at the rule set.  If you provide the appropriate tag, I can provide an answer.

Comment: What does the picture on the cover of the Players Handbook Look like?